# Hardcoding datefield and timefield values

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
timefield0 = new Ext.TimeField({});
datefield0 = new Ext.DateField({});

timefield0.setValue('9am');
datefield0.setValue('2009-09-09');
```

This does not work. Specified hardcoded parameter strings, which display properly, are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is completely incorrect. There is no Ext.TimeField but an Ext.form.TimeField, same goes for the DateField. Try this

```
var timefield0 = new Ext.form.TimeField({ name: 'time', renderTo: Ext.getBody() });
var datefield0 = new Ext.form.DateField({ name: 'date', renderTo: Ext.getBody() });

timefield0.setValue('9am');
datefield0.setValue('2009-09-09');
```